# SQL Select Statement Interview Query

Tags: sql

I was hit with the following question today during an interview:

> How many rows would the following SQL statement return given the two
>   tables A and B, where both A and B each have exactly 10 rows?:
>   `Select * from A, B;`

My answer was the obvious one: 20. However, my interviewer told me that it was allegedly 100, although he said that he didn't buy that himself. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That query returns a Cartesian product of tables `A` and `B`. Every row in table A will be matched with every row in table B. 10 rows * 10 rows = 100 rows.

You were probably interpreting that as a `UNION`, where all the rows in table B are **appended to the bottom** of the rows from table A. That query would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM A
UNION
SELECT * FROM B
```

Note that this would only work if the structures of `A` and `B` were identical.

Answer (score 2):

That's a cartesian JOIN.  All rows in A will be joined to each row in B, resulting in 100 rows in the output:

```
A1, B1
A1, B2
A1, B3
. . .
A2, B1
A2, B2
A2, B3,
. . .
A10, B8
A10, B9
A10, B10
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are selecting two tables without applying any join then database will automatically consider cartesian product as the default join.So you will have 100 rows as your result-set.

Answer (score 0):

This is the equivalent of using CROSS JOIN in T-SQL, so you'll get a Cartesian product, since you don't have an ON clause to relate the tables and you don't have a WHERE clause to filter the result.  See [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690(v=sql.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

When you don't use any join condition then SQL performs a **Cartesian product** and each row of your first table is mapped against each row of your second table.

You will get records as:

```
  table1row1   table2row1 
  table1row1   table2row2 
  table1row1   table2row3 
  ........
  ........
  table1row2   table2row1
  .....
  and so on 
  .....
```

table1row10   table2row10

**Thus you will get 100 records.**